# JavaScript Outdent text in contenteditable

Tags: javascript, execcommand

I am trying to indent and outdent in a contenteditable div. The indenting works perfectly but the outdent execCommand isn't working. I have a last key buffer that works for other keyboard shortcuts but not this one. Thank you for any help.

```
        if (keyCode == 9) { /* indent */
            event.preventDefault();
            document.execCommand("indent");
        }
        if(keyCode == 9 && lastkey == 16){
            event.preventDefault();
            document.execCommand("outdent");
        }
```

Comment: Are you trying to use pure JavaScript, or are you open to using jQuery or other libraries?

Comment: I can use other librarys but excluding jQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using an `if / else if` so that you're only running one of the two commands, and also have the `lastKey` check as the first in the series

I'm not sure how your `lastKey` variable was working, so I've added `event.shiftKey` for demo

```js
$(".myClass").on("keydown", function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode == 9 && event.shiftKey /* lastKey */ ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    document.execCommand("outdent");
  } else if (event.keyCode == 9) { /* indent */
    event.preventDefault();
    document.execCommand("indent");
  }
});
```

```css
.myClass {
  display: block;
  height: 300px;
  width: 500px;
  border: 1px solid #bfbfbf;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="myClass" contenteditable="true"></div>
```

---

Comment: Seems to be working in the code demo, I'll implament into my code. Thank you for your help. :)